# Can I run 24v LED strip lights over 14ga wire?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I want to wire up some LED strip lights.

Assuming I properly go through a transformer to the apropriate 24v the strip lights require (that is, the transformer these particular strip lights come with), is there any harm in me using 14ga wire, rather than 22ga, to bridge gaps of the LEDs?

e.g. the setup would look like:

```
    120v 15amp lightswitch
              V
  120v 15amp switched outlet
              V
24v strip light plug-in transformer
              V
strip light dimmer that comes with it
              V
14ga wire, branching four directions
              V
```

~3ft strips of LEDs (per branch)

I'm *not* talking about running LEDs off 120v AC current.

Can I run 24v current over 14ga wire for 8ft to power LEDs? Will the LEDs receive the power I'm trying to send them, or will they be too dim?

Comment: Not only is it a good idea... it's mandatory for longer distances than yours.  And you can get #14 cheap by raiding the "AC mains electrical" supply chain.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that's fine.

You can go down in gauge, as this means a thicker wire with less resistance.

If the manufacturer recommends 22Ga, and deems it sufficient, then you can use 14Ga.

A 14Ga wire is rated for 15A. This is independent from the voltage applied. The higher the voltage used, the more power can be delivered at 15A. At 24V (as in the LED example in the question), the wire can deliver 15A * 24V = 360W. At 120V (as for electrical house wiring), such wire can deliver 15A * 120V = 1800W.

In both cases the current through the wire is the same, and so are any heat losses due to the resistance of the wire. The wire will produce heat due to the current running through it.

14Ga electrical wire is rated for 15A per NEC. That number takes many factors into consideration including heat dissipation in a cable/wire bundle, location of installation, and thermal endurance of the jacket.

The OP's LEDs draw probably a fraction of that. We don't know from the question how much, but we know it's less because the LEDs come with 22Ga wire. 1 amp would be a good guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use 14ga

14ga can handle 15 Amp load, or 1800 Watts at 120 Volt

However at 24 Volt it can only handle 360 Watt at same 15 Amp capacity

or 18 LED with 20 watt each

Also the 14ga will have less voltage drop over 8 foot length than the 24ga, so that is good for your 24 Volt line.

Comment: In terms of thermal dissipation it is specified for 15A, which will deliver about 360W not 1800 in the OP's LED case.

Comment: @P2000 that would be 3 Amps load on 14 ga wire, are you making a mistake ?

Comment: 15A times 24V (not 120) is 360W, at least that's how I read the question

Comment: That would be the actual consumption 15x24, but the 14ga wire can carry 15 a at 120, 1800 Watt capacity

Comment: Thanks, I often forget it's `volts * watts = amps`

Comment: It will deliver 1800W if the voltage is 120. What you call capacity has nothing to do with voltage, only current. 15A at 24V or 120V is the same heat dissipation in the wire.

Comment: @JaminGrey no, it's volt * amp = watt. Your cable is current rated, not power rated.

Comment: More specifically, the thickness (diameter) of the wire determines the current carrying capacity. The insulation determines the safe voltage. Which is why high voltage (like 100,000 V or more!) lines are up on very tall towers - the wires are relatively thin and they may not be insulated at all, because insulation to protect from that voltage is expensive and heavy and limits heat dissipation. Cheaper to keep the lines bare but put them so high up that nobody sane will possibly reach them and far apart from each other to be safe (safest is either far apart or right next to each other - but

Comment: right next to each other needs appropriate insulation - easy 120V or 240V, not at high voltage).

Comment: @Ruskes Yes, as you say "14ga wire can carry 15 a at 120", but it certainly cant carry 75 amps! Which is what it would have to to deliver 1800 watts at 24 volts.